# Pipelines Agent artifact (with autologon = true) doesn't come online on Win 10

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-artifacts

I'm trying to use the Pipelines Agent artifact (windows-vsts-build-agent) to setup a new agent`:

- using Azure's Windows 10 image
- configured interactively (with autologon = true)
- with the goal to run UI Tests on it (through Azure Pipelines).

While the agent configuration succeeds (an entry is created in Agent Pool on Azure Pipelines), it shows as offline.

After logging in to this VM manually, I can see this screen:

[Choose Privacy Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2ppa.png)

After confirming this screen and logging into the VM manually, the agent comes up as expected.

Any ideas/hints what we can do, so the agent comes 'online' without the need for manual intervention?

Comment: Are you using a custom image?  Have you looked at https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/118840-enable-disable-privacy-settings-experience-sign-windows-10-a.html#option1

Comment: Yes, I have created a custom image with this setting disabled. now this issue is solved and I am able to login without any issue. but, I am trying to find any way using custom script extention or any script which will disable this setting during vm creation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below steps to disable the Privacy settings screen on VM startup.

1, Login Azure VM as adminstrator.

2, Press `win+r` and run `gpedit.msc` to Open the Local Group Policy Editor.

3, Navigate to `Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\OOBE` In the left pane of Local Group Policy Editor

4, Double click on the `Don't launch privacy settings experience on user logon policy` to edit it

5, Select **Enabled** to disable Privacy Settings Experience at Sign-in , click on OK,

If Local Group Policy Editor is unavailable in you Azure Vm. You can try edit the registry to disable it.

1, Press `win+r` and run `regedit`

2, navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\OOBE`

3, Change `DisablePrivacyExperience` DWORD to value `1`

See [this blog](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/118840-enable-disable-privacy-settings-experience-sign-windows-10-a.html) for more information.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but my question is a different one. I'm using autologon, with which the agent will automatically start itself. but the problem is I am getting a privacy settings screen, which requires manual intervention to accept it. I need to get past this screen without manual intervention.

Comment: Hi @saikartheekchalla I am afraid this issue comes from Azure VM, it is not in azure devops scope. See above updated answer

Comment: Hey @levi-lu-msft , thanks again. Yes, this is the problem I am trying to solve. But I need a way to enable this policy during the time of vm creation itself. becaue I am trying to automate vm creation and autologin and execute the UI automated tests. could you please lt me know if you have any idea on how to acheive this?

Comment: Hi @saikartheekchalla You can try [capturing the VM to a custom image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/capture-image-resource) after you have changed the registry. And create new VM from this custom image.